# Conversion between float and int, byte representation?

Tags: c

I have a question which deals with the difference in representation between a float and a byte in a computer system. So for instance how does a float convert from a float to and int and back; it results in a completely different representation of the bytes. Are there any resources I could use to point me in the right direction? Any help is much appreciated! I cannot find anything online, a link in the right direction would be very helpful!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: Some CPUs have instructions to perform integer to floating point conversion.  For example, on x86, you might use your `fist`.

Comment: I think I see "what" you are sking, but on the other hand answering it is a bit difficult. The computer -- or more to the point, the language handles the conversion and it's representation.  I think the wiki link is a good start and I'd also suggest that you consider writing a C program which dumps the hex representation of each otherwise equivalent value.

Comment: hmmm. I need to actually how the bits in one are related to the other, say 50 and 50.0 will have a different representation on the bit level. Basically I have to show how the computer goes from one to the other

Comment: So you need source code for a software-only implementation of the conversion, working entirely by bit manipulation? Which isn't really how "the computer" goes from one to the other, if "the computer" is my PC, since my PC doesn't do it in software, it does it using hardware that's logically equivalent to the software but works rather differently. But it is how "a computer" might do it.

Comment: I just need to know how a computer does it since they have a completely different representation, yet 50 is == 50.0. I have to show the "correlation" between them

Comment: OK, well the computer does it using several thousand logic gates on an integrated circuit somewhere in the processor. Which of those gates are you particularly interested in? ;-)

Comment: Ok, if we have 1234 it is 00 00 04 d2, if we have 1234.0 then we get 44 9a 40 00. They look completely different yet they equal the same. How does the float get derived from the int. Say if a comparison must happen, the processor will try and cast the into into a float.

Comment: @user1260028: maybe read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision, then come back with specific questions if you still don't see how an algorithm might be designed to convert to and from floating point format.

Comment: is it not simply a conversion from base 2 to base 10 and back?

Comment: Correct, it is not. Neither `float` nor `int` is stored in base 10.

Comment: I'm kind of going of this http://www.digitconvert.com/

Comment: @SteveJessop your link actually answers my question. You should put the answer up or something so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common encoding of floating-point numbers uses IEEE 754. For single-precision numbers, there is a sign bit (s), 8 exponent bits (e), and 23 fraction bits (f).

For most values of s, e, and f, the value represented is -1<sup>s</sup>•2<sup>e-127</sup>•F, where F is the number you get by writing “1.” followed by the 23 bits of f and then interpreting that string as a binary numeral. E.g., if f is 10000000000000000000000, then the binary numeral is 1.10000000000000000000000, which is (in decimal) 1.5, so F is 1.5.

The above holds whenever 0 < e < 255. The values 0 and 255 are special.

When e is 0, the value represented is the same as above except that you start F with “0.” instead of “1.”. In particular, if f is zero, then the value represented is zero. If f is not zero, these are called denormal numbers, because they are smaller than the normal values represented in the primary way above.

When e is 255 and f is 0, the value represented is +infinity or -infinity, according to the sign bit, s. When e is 255 and f is not zero, the value represented is called a NaN, Not a Number, which is used for debugging or catching errors or other special purposes. There are quiet NaNs (which do not cause traps; they are typically used when you want to continue calculations to get a final result, then figure out what to do about a NaN) and signaling NaNs (which do cause traps; they are typically used when you want to abort a calculation because an error has occurred).

There may be variations in how the encoding appears on different platforms, especially the ordering of bytes within the 32 bits. And some platforms do not use IEEE 754 encodings.

Double-precision encoding uses the same scheme, except e is 11 bits, the 127 (called the exponent bias) is changed to 1023, and f is 52 bits. Also the special value for the exponent is its 11-bit maximum, 2047, rather than the 8-bit maximum, 255.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard does not specify how floating-point values are represented.  Each implementation/platform is free to implement floating-point numbers however they see fit.  There are certain constraints that the implementations must adhere to, but the bit-level representation is implementation defined.

Since you can't predict how a floating-point number will be stored or represented in general, there is no real way to answer this question as written.  If you have a particular floating-point implementation in mind, we may be able to provide some details.  Those details, however, would only be relevant to that specific implementation.  Also note that different CPU architectures may convert values differently, even if they use the same floating-point representation.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, it is dangerous to think of floating point values as being "exact".  Once you have a fraction, a float will probably be approximate.  (If the fraction can be exactly expressed in binary, it might still be exact, like `1/2`.  But for example, `1/10` will be an approximate value.)

Several people have pointed you to Wikipedia articles.  Read those.  Basically, a float value is a sign bit, an exponent, and a mantissa.  If you have a float value of `50.0` then the float value will look nothing like the integer representation of `50`.  (Original incorrect discussion deleted; see comments for details.)

There is no simple way to transform an integer to a float or vice versa.  The CPU of your computer has built-in instructions to do the transformation for you, or you can write a program that will do it, but there isn't a simple trick.

EDIT: Above was edited to remove a part where I wrote some incorrect stuff.  @Eric Postpischil pointed out the major mistake I made: a value of 50 would be stored as a fractional value raised to a power greater than one, not what I originally said.  That was a dumb mistake, and I apologize.  He also pointed out that the "mantissa" part is technically the "significand"; I will simply say that I have often seen it called the "mantissa", whether that is correct or not.

I'll repeat the important part: there is no simple way to transform an integer to a float or vice versa.

Comment: Floating-point values do not have mantissas; they have significands (or fractions). (Mantissas are fractional parts of logarithms.) In the common IEEE 754 encodings, the significand represents a value between 0 (inclusive) and 2 (exclusive) (1 to 2 for normal values, 0 to 1 for denormals). The unbiased exponent of 50 would be 5, not 1, so the biased exponent would be 132. The significand would be 1.5625, encoded with the 23 bits 10100000000000000000000.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Technically correct, but it was common parlance to call the bits after the exponent the mantissa, and the habit is hard to lose. Also, mantissa is the nicer word.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, thank you for pointing out my silly mistake.  I edited the answer in response.  I have a question: is there any valid 24-bit integer that cannot be represented by an exact floating point value in single-precision?  Since we must raise a significand to an exponent, it seems that there must be some values that can't be reproduced exactly (such as prime numbers).  If so, it's not just fractions that must be considered approximate.  Even integer values, if not a clean power of two, may be approximate as floats.

Comment: @steveha: Every integer in [-2**24, 2**24] can be represented exactly. Proof: 2**24 is (0, 24, 0) (sign bit, unbiased exponent, encoded significand), 0 is (0, 0, 0). For any integer x in (0, 2**24), its encoding is (0, floor(log[2](x)), x/2**(23-floor(log[2](x)))-2**23). The exponent is clearly an integer in [0, 24). The encoded significand is valid (an integer in [0, 2**23), thus, 23 bits) by this proof: x/floor(log[2](x)) is clearly in [1, 2), so x/2**(23-floor(log[2](x))) is in [2**23, 2**24), so subtracting 2**23 yields something in [0, 2**23). It is an integer because...

Comment: its low bit is at least 1/2**(23-floor(log[2](x))), and floor(log[2](x)) is at most 23, so this is at least 1/2**(23-23), which is 1. The negative numbers follow symmetrically.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, wow, thank you for that very complete explanation.

Comment: Oops, had the exponent sign wrong. x/2**(23-...) should be x*2**(23-...) wherever it appears. The idea is to scale x down to [1, 2), then multiply it by 2**23 to form the 23 bits of the encoded significand.

Answer (score 0):

The representations of `float` and `int` on a specific platforms are strictly defined and known to the C compiler on that platform. Which means that there is always a well-defined algorithm for converting one to another. In practice, when the natural platform-specific types are used, the conversion is performed internally by the CPU (FPU). The CPU has a dedicated command that that reads the `float` data from memory into the internal CPU registers. Another command can then write that data back into memory as an `int` value. And vice versa.

For example, on x86 platform a `float_value = int_value` assigment will be generally translated into a sequence of CPU commands like

```
fld int_value   ; read `int` value from `int_value` to the internal register
fst float_value ; save `float` value from the internal register to `float_value`
```

When it comes to converting arithmetic data types that are not immediately supported by the hardware, C compiler has to spell out all necessary conversion steps literally in the generated code. Sometimes one might need support for integer or floating-point types that are not even supported by the language, in which case one has to implement the conversion manually.